# Sharing a landing page in LinkedIn: wrong image

Tags: linkedin-api

I am having some issues sharing this link on LinkedIn but not in other Social Media platforms: https://formscloud.iese.edu/landings-open-day-pamplona-sept-2017 . I have implemented correctly the Script for the Open Graph but it seems to be fetching another image than the one i told it to. The script is taken from a previous landing page and it is working on that one, but doesn't seem to be working on this one. I've seen LinkedIn actually has a buffer for shared content of 7 days.

I would need it now, I wanted to know if you can give me a hand on this and may be able to re-crawl my page.

**Code**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="IESE Business School" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="formscloud.iese.edu/landings-executive-open-day-sep‌​t-palma-2017/…; 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="iese.edu/Aplicaciones/upload/FTranking171222x649.pn‌​g " /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="MBA - IESE Business School" />
```

It's on `<head>`

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: <meta property="og:title" content="IESE Business School" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://formscloud.iese.edu/landings-executive-open-day-sept-palma-2017/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.iese.edu/Aplicaciones/upload/FTranking171222x649.png
" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="MBA - IESE Business School" />


It's on <head>

Answer (score 0):

Your image seems to be too big (more than 8 MB) so it is picking the next file. Try reducing your file size and it should work.

Please keep in mind that since your other image has been cached it may take some time for new image to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have absolutely no idea how LinkedIn is choosing the thumbnail for sharing your webpage, insert your URL into the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

So, thanks to the magic of Archive.org, I am able to see [a copy of the HTML on your page.](http://view-source:https://web.archive.org/web/20170720150955/http://formscloud.iese.edu/landings-open-day-pamplona-sept-2017/) .  So, here's the problem for your page most likely...

```
<meta property="og:image"
content="https://web.archive.org/web/20170720150955im_/http://www.iese.edu/Aplicaciones/upload/FTranking171222x649.png

"/>
```

You need to close properties like this: `<meta location="someurl">`.  What you have is: `<meta location="someurl (linebreak) ">`.

Also, it appears that your image never existed or was uploaded: [`OG:` Image Tag 404.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170720150955im_/http://www.iese.edu/Aplicaciones/upload/FTranking171222x649.png)